# Xcode利用中のescキーについて

Tags: xcode

Xcodeでimage.xcassets等の項目名を編集しているとき、escキーを押下するとlと文字が入力されます。
編集をcancelしたいためにescキーを押しているため、キャンセルをしたいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか。

### 環境

- MacOSX 10.11.2
- Xcode 7.2
- キーは日本語配列

Answer (score 1):

編集前に戻したいという事であれば、

- 項目名を全部消して編集を終了する
- 編集終了後に「command + z」

あたりで戻せると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
esc自体の動きを変えることは可能でしょうか？（何度も間違ってしまい手間なので・・・）

Comment: @Y.Keisuke  Text Editing, Key Bindingsあたりを見てみましたが、それっぽいのは見つけられませんでした（Use Escape key to show completion suggestionsというのがありますが、これは別物のようです）。

Comment: やはりそうですか・・・。確認していただき、ありがとうございました！。